# Repair tree structure in c

Tags: c, algorithm, tree

I have a tree structure in c (quadtree) which I want to clean to avoid long tree branches. Here is an example:

Instead of this tree structure,

[image]

I want to clean up the tree to get this structure (Same information, less memory consumption, faster tree walks).

[image]

Here the red node is the root of the tree. Blue nodes are empty and black nodes are tree nodes which carry information.

My tree has the following structure in c:

```
typedef enum{particle, pseudo_particle} node_type;

typedef struct{
    double m;
    double x[DIM];
    int to_delete;
} Particle;

typedef struct{
    double x_min[DIM];
    double x_max[DIM];
} tree_box;

typedef struct tree_node{
    Particle p;
    tree_box box;
    node_type node;
    struct tree_node *child[4];
} tree_node;
```

The function which cleans up the tree

```
void clean_tree(tree_node *t){
    if(t != NULL){
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            clean_tree(t->child[i]);
        }
        // Operation on *t
        if(t->node != particle){
            int child_counter = 0;
            int d = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
                if(t->child[i] != NULL) {
                    if(t->child[i]->p.to_delete == TRUE){
                        free(t->child[i]);
                        t->child[i] = NULL;
                    }
                    else {
                        child_counter++;
                        d=i;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(child_counter == 0) {
                t->p.to_delete = TRUE;
            }else if (child_counter == 1) {
                t = t->child[d];
                free(t->child[d]);
                t->child[d] = NULL;
            }
        }
        // End of operation on *t
    }
}
```

But here is the problem: After calling clean_tree() my tree structure is no longer existent. The whole tree gets deleted. But why? Does someone see my error?

Comment: Is this actual code? You test for `child_counter`, but increment `son_counter`, leaving `child_counter` always 0. And what about the daughters? Someone think of the daughters!

Comment: Where is `son_counter` defined? What's the significance of the node type? The code you show defines and sets `child_counter` to 0, then the next reference to `child_counter` is `if(child_counter == 0) { t->p.to_delete = TRUE; }...` which looks to me like you are asking it to delete everything.

Comment: If it's real code, then at global level and the observed misbehaviour is explained. But chances are, that it is some untested pseudocode and it was just a writing mistake...

Comment: What happened when you single-stepped through the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you _surely_ have in your debugger?

Comment: @Ctx I corrected the code.

Comment: @Samuel to be honest, I do not have much motivation to think through this non-trivial code having in mind, there may be more relevant diversions from your production code, which make finding your mistake impossible. You should provide a working MCVE (which you really compiled and tested)

Comment: @Samuel, why don't you add your fix with an explanation so that other people can take help from it?

Comment: @Abhijit I just corrected a spelling error.

Comment: @Samuel More a typing error than a spelling error

Comment: @Samuel, are you still looking for someone to fix your issue?

Comment: @Abhijit Sure. I think the problem is probably here: `t = t->child[d]; free(t->child[d]); t->child[d] = NULL; I am not sure if I copy the data of the tree nodes properly.

Comment: @Samuel, Give me some time. I will look into your code and see whether I can help you or not. Currently busy in office.

Answer (score 0):

I verified your code.

What you are  doing is that you are traversing the  tree and when you found that all the child nodes of a three node are null you are setting it to be delete or you are deleting the parent node who’s all the child nodes are null or deleted. Till that I can understand you did right. But when there is only one child node exist and rest are null or deleted you are deleting child of it with same index, which is not understandable for me.

```
     if(child_counter == 0) {   
            t->p.to_delete = TRUE;// Here you are setting the parent node to be deleted while you found that all the child nodes are null or you deleted them in the above
            //but instead of this you should delete the node here itself like  free(t); and you don’t need to call the method `clear_tree` again
        }else if (child_counter == 1) {
            t = t->child[d];     //as t is a local pointer to the current function(recursive) function. Once it return to its previous call the t in that function is holding the address of different node
            free(t->child[d]); //why are you deleting this node? By doing it you are deleting the whole tree
           //this child node might have a branches in it. Instead of deleting it you should store its address in parents node’s child node list or if this is the only node of the tree just leave it
            t->child[d] = NULL;
        }
```

Your problem is exactly at the above code. Just follow my comments and it might help you to fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you the the response. If a node has only one `child` I want this child to go one level up so I thought copying would be right and so I did `t = t->child[d]`. That means, that the node above the child node becomes the new `child`. By doing this I wanted to repair the tree. But what could I do instead if my approach was wrong? What I want is just that the mother node adopts the properties of the child node and then I wanted to delete the child node since it is no longer of use. Please help me if you can.